# How to configure driver for Gigabyte Wi-Fi adapter?

Tags: networking, 18.04, drivers, wireless

I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver) on my desktop this evening - I use Linux VMs (purely CLI based) at work all the time so I'm familiar with Linux but new to Ubuntu, and configuring WiFi adapters in Linux for that matter.

I have a Gigabyte GC-WB1733D-I PCI-E WiFi adapter and my WiFi settings currently say 'No WiFi adapter found'. I have had a look around and followed a few tutorials and YouTube videos where you are instructed to run clone a Git repo and then run some scripts that are downloaded - none of these have worked for me.

My adapter is based on Intel Wireless-AC 9260. I found a firmware download for this [here](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html), but even after downloading and reading the README, I'm not entirely sure what to do as the instructions are generic i.e. not distribution specific so it doesn't give direct instructions. It did say to copy the `iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode` file to `/lib/firmware` which I have done, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: As requested, the output of running `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list; uname -a` is:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1043:85f0]
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 [8086:2526] (rev 29)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0014]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070] [10de:1b81] (rev a1)
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
Linux aidan-desktop 5.3.0-46-generic #38~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 31 04:17:56 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Also, output of `dmesg | grep iwl` is:

```
[   16.849713] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   16.911415] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:07:00.0 failed with error -110
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list; uname -a` terminal command.

Comment: Also please add output of `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: @Pilot6 have added the outputs.

Comment: This is a kernel bug or a hardware failure. You can report this bug to launchpad and try to use another kernel.

Comment: Would you recommend using the previous version of the kernel?

Comment: I strongly suspect that `dmesg | grep iwl` contains many more lines than the two above. Please reboot, run the command again and show us the last three lines.

Comment: @chili555 Yes it does now (also, the WiFi networks are now showing up, however when I try to connect to one my system freezes and I have to reboot):
`[   40.887223] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   41.001236] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   41.064235] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring`

Answer (score 1):

Open another terminal windows and run `journalctl -f` there.

Then load driver using:

- `sudo modprobe -rv iwlwifi`
- `sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi`

and look what happens in logs.

- Run in terminal: `nmcli dev wifi` to see if it works showing hotspots in the neighborhood.

If it does not help, then try:

- Download [backports](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/) package for your kernel (`uname -a`).
- Extract it: `tar xvfz backports-somekernelversion.tar.gz`
- `cd backports-somekernelversion`
- `make defconfig-iwlwifi`
- `make`
- `sudo make install`
- Reboot
- `sudo update-initramfs -u` if previous reboot didn't help
- Reboot

If this does not work, you could uninstall this by:

- `cd ~/Downloads/backports-somekernelversion`
- `sudo make uninstall`

Try to put [firmwares from 19.10](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_OUQUXo4V7AbbzPsqYCV2ck6h_wqKTCc/view?usp=sharing) into `/lib/firmware` folder:

```
$ ls /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-
iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-33.ucode  iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-41.ucode
iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode  iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-43.ucode
iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode  iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode


$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep 9260
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
```

Find out if your driver installed somewhere:

```
find /lib/modules/ -iname *9260*.ko
```

For my system I have the next output:

```
$ find /lib/modules/ -iname *cfg80211*.ko
/lib/modules/5.3.0-40-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
/lib/modules/5.3.0-40-lowlatency/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
/lib/modules/5.3.0-45-lowlatency/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
/lib/modules/5.3.0-45-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
```

Comment: However, in Ubuntu, firmware is located in /lib/firmware. Is it to be copied to itself??

Comment: @chili555 Yes, you are rigth.

Comment: @Gryu Thank you for your response - I didn't get anything when running the hotspot test, and I followed the second section however unfortunately my WiFi adapter is still not working :( Really appreciate the help nonetheless!

Comment: Try to put the next drivers into your `/lib/firmware`. They are on my 19.10 by default there: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_OUQUXo4V7AbbzPsqYCV2ck6h_wqKTCc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Gryu still nothing even after rebooting, have copied them inside a folder named `intelwifi` and in the main `firmware` directory.

Comment: What does `cat /proc/modules | grep iwl` command show?

Comment: `iwlwifi 348160 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000 (OE)
cfg80211 704512 1 iwlwifi, Live 0x0000000000000000 (OE)
compat 16384 2 iwlwifi,cfg80211, Live 0x0000000000000000 (OE)`

Answer (score 0):

### I documented my setup process for the Gigabyte GC-WB1733D-I NIC. I was using Debian at the time, but since Ubuntu and Debian are close relatives much of it should be viable on either system.

How to set up the Gigabyte GC-WB1733D-I chip (Intel 9260 Chipset) on Debian Buster

> In case Ubuntu does not include the firmware you need, you can easily download the necessary firmware from Intels website. Otherwise, you should be able to skip steps 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3.

**1** Install the driver directly from Intel

**1.1** Download the iwlwifi firmware package required for your chipset (9260)

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html

**1.2** Decompress and access the firmware package

```
tar zxvf iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-34.618819.0.tgz

cd iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-34.618819.0
```

**1.3** Move the firmware into /lib/firmware

```
sudo cp iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode /lib/firmware
```

**2** Install bluetooth utilities

```
sudo apt-get install bluetooth bluez bluez-tools rfkill blueman
```

**3** Deactivate preexisting wifi and bluetooth controllers in the BIOS. Recommended as the onboard controllers would otherwise be defaulted to by the OS.

- Disable onboard bluetooth controller
- Disable onboard wifi controller

You could of course manage several bluetooth / wifi controllers

**4** Make sure your bluetooth device is not blocked. Verify via rfkill utility:

```
sudo rfkill list
```

**4.1** If the bluetooth device is either hard or soft blocked, unblock via rfkill utility:

```
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

**4.2** Make sure the bluetooth service is active

```
sudo service bluetooth start
```

**5** In case the new wifi interface does not show up in ifconfig

**5.1** Unload conflicting modules

```
sudo modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
```

**5.2** Reinsert iwlwifi module

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi; sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

source: https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi

**6** If you were previously connected to an access point with another NIC you will most likely be automatically connected to it again once you restart your device otherwise you should be able to set up a new connection with the network manager.

The bluetooth connection can be easily set up using the previously installed blueman utility which includes a GUI bluetooth manager.